# Google App Engine: appcfg.py rollback

Tags: google-app-engine, rollback

I'm using Windows 7 and for the life of me I cannot figure out how to call the rollback function on appcfg.py. All I want to know is what to type into the command prompt so I can rollback my app.

Comment: You can increase your application version number in "app.yaml" file --- in case "appcfg.py rollback <dir>" command doesn't works!

Comment: For the path to appcfg when using android studio see:
[appcfg path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45560377/3264522)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The rollback command can rollback a transaction on the server, but you are unlikely to need to use that unless an `update` of your app failed for some reason. You should be getting some feedback from appcfg.py that such an action is required. Is that what you want to do? If so, just open a command prompt and type `appcfg.py rollback`.

Otherwise, please let us know what you are trying to accomplish by performing a 'rollback'.

Comment: Yeah, the update failed. The error message is: 

Another transaction by user User is already in progress for this app and major version. That user can undo the transaction with appcfg.py's "rollback" command.

This "in-progress" transaction the error code refers to started last friday. I think it might be because I quit out of the google app engine launcher when it was launching. Anyway, I want deploy a new version of the app and it won't work. 

Typing "appcfg.py rollback" only opened appcfg.py inside Notepad++, and did nothing else. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @petwoip: It sounds like your system is not configured to automatically use the Python interpreter to launch .py files. You should be able to run it with "python appcfg.py rollback"

Comment: Ah, of course! I put the path of my app at the end and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 39):

Try this: `appcfg.py rollback <directory>`

If your application **myapp** resides in `C:\Users\Nilesh\Documents\`  then directory path should be `C:\Users\Nilesh\Documents\myapp`

If you installed *Google App Engine Launcher* in your system, then installation path should be something like this `C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine`

Now open the command prompt and type the following:

```
C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine>appcfg.py rollback C:\Users\Nilesh\Documents\myapp
```

This will solve your issue. :)

Answer (score 13):

```
E:\eclipse-jee-indigo-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.6.1.v201201120043r37\appengine-java-sdk-1.6.1\bin>appcfg.cmd rollback E:\AdminApp\Admin\war
```

For Rollback Java Application

Answer (score 8):

try this :
this was how I did it (all from the command line) which is a slightly simpler
method, which achieved the same effect.....

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Amit\My Documents\newproject>"C:\Program
Files\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.2.5.v200909021031\appengine-java-sdk-1.2.5\bin\appcfg" rollback war


Reading application configuration data...
2009-09-17 20:47:35.859::INFO:  Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
Beginning server interaction for idebanet...
0% Rolling back the update.
Success.
Cleaning up temporary files...

C:\Documents and Settings\Amit\My Documents\newproject>
```

Comment: This answer saved my app (and time), thank you [aMit](http://stackoverflow.com/users/481062/amit)

Answer (score 7):

If you use maven for deploying your app (with goal `appengine:update`), then you can also run maven with goal `appengine:rollback`. It solved the issue for me.

Comment: thank you very much, so much easier than trying to hunt down some stupid python script.

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't get mine to work, until I did this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine>python appcfg.py rollback "C:\Pro
gram Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\mirror-quickstart-python"
```

I had to add in the double quotes and "python" before the appcfg.py

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I did this on my Linux machine (after many trials and errors):

```
cd ~/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.5.0_155965261/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.5.1.r35v201106211634/appengine-java-sdk-1.5.1/bin
chmod +x appcfg.sh
./appcfg.sh -s appengine.google.com -e [my-email]@gmail.com rollback /home/erelsgl/workspace/ImitatorGWT/war
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

10, I had this problem little while ago and I have resolved it.

First, I moved to bin directory using:

```
cd ~/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.5.0_155965261/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.5.1.r35v201106211634/appengine-java-sdk-1.5.1/bin
```

Then, I ran the rollback command:

```
./appcfg.sh rollback /home/workspace/vchat/war
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Here I have fix it on my ubuntu machine:

```
cd /home/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.6.5/appengine-java-sdk-1.6.5/bin/
sh ./appcfg.sh -A appId -s appengine.google.com -e youdID@google.com rollback /home/workspace/projectName/war
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

For all those who deploy using Google App Engine Launcher, you can fix the issue by opening command prompt and `python appcfg.py rollback <directory of your application>`

In my case, I have not set up Python env variable so:

```
C:\Python25\python C:\Program Files\Google\Google App Engine\appcfg.py rollback C:\eclipse\applicatoin
```

Answer (score 0):

In Linux uploading an App through appcfg creates a staging directory in /tmp

0% Created staging directory at: '/tmp/appcfg8593320566371318406.tmp'

To rollback you may also this directory in rollback command

```
appcfg.sh -A yourAppId -s appengine.google.com rollback /tmp/appcfg8593320566371318406.tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the game, but I'd like to add what worked for me in Windows XP.  In a command prompt:

```
C:\Python27>python C:\Progra~1\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py rollback C:\Docume~1\myname\MyDocu~1\Projects\myproject\
```

Python 2.7 and the short names in the Windows path were key.

Answer (score 0):

- Open dos
- place yourself in the folder containing appcfg.cmd (bin of the GAE SDK)
- If your application **myapp** resides in `C:\Users\Nilesh\Documents\`  then directory path should be `C:\Users\Nilesh\Documents\myapp\war`.
- Now open the command prompt and type the following:

  appcfg.cmd rollback C:\Users\Nilesh\Documents\myapp\war

Note don't forget to add 'war' at then end of your app folder

- then enter your email and password

Answer (score 0):

I am using 64 bit Windows7 with GAE-Java  Typing all this detail at the command prompt can be frustrating.  My solution: create a batch file.

1. I created a batch file named 'rollback.bat' & saved it in my WORKSPACE directory.  The contents look like this:

   ```
   cd C:\Users\Organize4Joy\My Code\EclipseWORKSPACE\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.3\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.3\bin\appcfg.cmd rollback C:\Users\Organize4Joy\EclipseWORKSPACE\iTreewareMAIN\war
   ```
2. run the batch file by simply typing "rollback"
   this local utility changes directory, runs the appcfg rollback EXE & points it to my war directory.

Even better would be to establish a common utility(bin) directory and add it to my path variable.  That way I can run this utility from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

After experiencing quite a it of frustration trying to 'appcfg rollback' on my Mac, I read Jaky's answer and resolved the problem in a couple of minutes by changing the version number.

If you're using eclipse, just open the appengine-web.xml under war>WEB-INF in the project & change the version number there.

Answer (score 0):

1. Traverse to the path where the `appcfg.py` is placed
2. Run the Command `python appcfg.py rollback` (The Directory of your project folder)

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered many times, but I had issues getting it to work for me too. If you are *running Java* and are also having problems or if you have Google's *2 factor authentication* setup and that is giving you problems, here are the steps I used to make it succeed:

**1)** Make sure you have the Google App Engine in your Path in Environment variables. 
IE: C:\Users\yourUserName\Desktop\Eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.9.18\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.18\bin

**2)** Open up a command window AS AN ADMINISTRATOR! Do not just type cmd and enter, you need to type cmd, right-click on it, and open as admin

**3)** First, CD to the folder that has the WAR file in it. In my case, that was:
cd "C:\Users\yourUserName\Documents\MyWorkspace\Project1"
This is the same folder that has the src, .settings, and war folders in it.

**4)** In the cmd window, type: "appcfg rollback war" and press enter.

**5)** It will ask for your google credentials. If you do not have 2 factor authentication setup, simply type them in and press enter and you will be set.

**6)** If you DO have 2 factor authentication setup, go to your google accounts page (Just google for 'google account') and it will be the first or second one.
Next, under the "Signing In" category, go to App passwords.
Next, go to the bottom and under the select app dropdown menu, choose other and type in anything (IE: GAE rollback)
It will give you a password (16 digit random numbers). 
Finally, type in your email address in the command window and then type/ paste in this new temporary 16 digit password into the password section.

**7)** Profit!

-Sil

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to use the --no_cookies, without it, I had no premissions to do the operation.

C:\Users\user_name.gradle\appengine-sdk\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.30\bin\appcfg --no_cookies --application=app_name --version=1 rollback C:\projects\android\app\backend\build\exploded-app

Answer (score -3):

I don't know much about these coding things everyone is talking about here..but I found a simple way to update the application..

1. Select your application and click on "EDIT".
2. A wordpad file should open up with application details.
3. Below the application there is version:1
4. Simply change the version to version:2 instead of 1 and click "Save".
5. So, instead of updating the same version..you are deploying a new version..
6. Click on "DEPLOY".
7. Check your application now!