# what is this error when deploying google python-appengine application?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

this is the error message .. any help will be appreciated .

```
2011-02-23 23:09:11 Running command: "['C:\\Python25\\pythonw.exe', '-u', 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\google_appengine\\appcfg.py', '--no_cookies', u'--email=adham587@gmail.com', '--passin', 'update', 'C:\\Users\\adham\\Desktop\\images']"
Application: refacingme; version: 1.
Server: appengine.google.com.
Scanning files on local disk.
Initiating update.
2011-02-23 23:09:42,223 WARNING appengine_rpc.py:405 ssl module not found.
Without the ssl module, the identity of the remote host cannot be verified, and
connections may NOT be secure. To fix this, please install the ssl module from
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ssl .
To learn more, see http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/general.html#rpcssl . 
Password for XXXXX@gmail.com: Error 409: --- begin server output ---
Another transaction by user XXXXXXXX is already in progress for this app and major version. That user can undo the transaction with appcfg.py's "rollback" command.
--- end server output ---
2011-02-23 23:09:46 (Process exited with code 1)

You can close this window now.
```

Comment: `To fix this, please install the ssl module from
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ssl` -- it says it all.

Comment: @sukhbir: That lack of ssl is just a warning. It is not causing the problem that @adham is seeing.

Comment: Yes brothers , i'm looking for a soluion for the problem ?! .. what is Error 409 mean ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem can occur if an `update` is started and does not finish for whatever reason. As the error message notes, the correct thing to do is to give appcfg.py the `rollback` command. That will undo the failed changes and reset your app so it is ready for an update.

Comment: i think you mean somthing like this http://techperience.blogspot.com/2010/07/app-engine-deploy-error-409-solution.html

Comment: If you want to avoid a rollback, you can simply increase the version number.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
easy_install ssl
```

The message says that module is missing.

@Adam: duly noted. I apologize for missing the "Warning text".

I believe his error will go away in a while since another operation might be going on at the same time. He should install ssl module nevertheless. If after a while and it doesn't help, he should perform a rollback.

[Google App Engine: appcfg.py rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215140/google-app-engine-appcfg-py-rollback)

Comment: That is just a warning and it has nothing to do with @adhams error