# django non-rel rollback

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I cancelled a deployment to GAE while using django non-rel's manage.py deploy.

Now when I try to redeploy it says Another transaciton is already in progress and use appcfg to rollback.

But django non-rel doesn't have appcfg.py so how can I rollback or fix this issue?

I've scoured the internet and can't find any answers. I've waited about half an hour and it still displays this message.

Comment: Do any of the solutions here work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215140/google-app-engine-appcfg-py-rollback

Comment: I don't have access to appcfg.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

manage.py deploy calls appcfg.py in order to deploy.

appcfg.py is in the SDK.  you must have the SDK installed somewhere if "manage.py deploy" is working.  you can look around for it, or download the SDK again.

There's no reason you don't have access to appcfg.py

If you need more help finding it, add details about what platform you're running on, where you installed the appengine SDK and where your python folder is.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "I don't have access to appcfg.py"?

Try going to cmd (for windows), navigate to your app directory, and type in the following:

```
appcfg.py rollback .
```

Hit return (enter key) and see if that works. If not, what does it display?