# How to appcfg rollback my project?

Tags: google-app-engine, cmd

I am using **Google App Engine** to upload my python project However once I try to upload my project I receive this error:

```
2013-07-24 20:21:06 Running command: "['C:\\Python26\\python.exe', '-u', 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\google_appengine\\appcfg.py', '--no_cookies', u'--email=thomasston54321@gmail.com', '--passin', 'update', 'C:\\Users\\Thomas Stone\\Documents\\proxy-server']"
08:21 PM Host: appengine.google.com
08:21 PM Application: mathsonlinegames; version: secureable
08:21 PM 
Starting update of app: mathsonlinegames, version: secureable
08:21 PM Getting current resource limits.
Password for thomasston54321@gmail.com: 08:21 PM Scanning files on local disk.
Error 409: --- begin server output ---
Another transaction by user Thomasston54321 is already in progress for app: s~mathsonlinegames, version: secureable. That user can undo the transaction with "appcfg rollback".
--- end server output ---
2013-07-24 20:21:16 (Process exited with code 1)

You can close this window now.
```

Because of this I have tried this in **CMD**:

```
cd C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine
appcfg.py rollback C:\Users\Thomas Stone\Documents\proxy-server
```

But then I receive this error in **CMD**

```
Usage: appcfg.py [options] rollback <directory> | <file>

appcfg.py: error: Expected a single <directory> or <file> argument.
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to cd into the src folder.

Then do:

```
appcfg.py --no_cookies --email=YOUR_EMAIL_HERE@gmail.com --passin rollback ./
```

That always does the trick for me.

Comment: I still receive this error:                        `Usage: appcfg.py [options] rollback <directory> | <file>`

`appcfg.py: error: Expected a single <directory> or <file> argument.`

Comment: were you in the same filepath that is listed when you upload the app to GAE?

Comment: No i was not should i change it back

Comment: yeah if you look in the app engine launcher at that exact filepath that is where you should be when you run this command

Comment: Haha you're welcome, I've had so many questions answered on here I'm glad to help someone else out.

Answer (score 4):

If you are unsuccessful trying above steps, place your app.yaml inside C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine.

Then run:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine>appcfg.py --no_cookies --email=Youremail --passin rollback app.yaml
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Using the command line **GO to** the location where  **google_apengine** folder is present in my case it C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine.

```
appcfg.py --no_cookies --email=yourEmail  rollback [ project_dir\]app.yaml
```

in my case [project_dir="E:\practiceCode\wp_test"]

so  command  should be

```
appcfg.py --no_cookies --email=prabhatyadav03@gmail.com  rollback E:\practiceCode\wp_test\app.yaml
```

and you get the authentication verification and  complete that and rollback done.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java Eclipse GAE, this worked for me.

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.36\bin>appcfg --no_cookies --email=youremail@gmail.com --passin rollback "C:\eclipse\workspace\project-id\war"`

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what went wrong in my deployment so deployed was not done the same error 409 i got and by seeing the all the comments on stackoverflow related issues finally found the solution to it

it worked for me on MAC OS

Mac navigate to this Path on terminal below

/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine

and used this code to update it

python appcfg.py rollback /Users/ram/Desktop/checkout_workspace/website-appengine/app.yaml

and Rolled back my update.

Answer (score 0):

When using gradle the path to appcfg is:

```
<user-dir>/.gradle/appengine-sdk/appengine-java-sdk-<version>/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

This was nagging for me for a while. 
- It would be nice if Android Studio had this built in, like in the "stop deploying" functionality.

Finding the appropriate target folder took some work, but this worked as a gradle user on Mac OSX Sierra:

```
$ /Users/myuser/.gradle/appengine-sdk/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.54/bin/appcfg.sh rollback ~/Projects/myproject1.appspot.com-v74/backend/build/exploded-app/
```

A couple of steps are required to get there, however:
1.) set appcfg.sh, AND run_java.sh to executable (using chmod):

```
$ cd /Users/myuser/.gradle/appengine-sdk/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.54/bin/
$ chmod u+x appcfg.sh  
$ chmod u+x run_java.sh
```

2.) run the script:

```
$ /Users/myuser/.gradle/appengine-sdk/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.54/bin/appcfg.sh rollback ~/Projects/myproject1.appspot.com-v74/backend/build/exploded-app/
```

3.) enter credentials in the window that pops up
4.) copy/paste the "code" supplied in the window into the terminal session.

This also worked for me when I put the command into a shell script using:

```
$ vi ~/bin/rollback-project1
i  (press "i" for insert mode)
command-v (paste the command above)
:wq   (to save it, exit)
```

Run the script:

```
$ rollback-project1
```

If this fails, make sure that ~/bin is in your PATH:

```
echo $PATH
```

if not, add it to your ~/.bash_profile file (or whatever file applies):
export PATH="~/bin:$PATH"

Answer (score -1):

```
appcfg.py rollback ./
```

all you need...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10619900)

Comment: @OndrejTucny Why not?