# GAE appcfg rollback not working: 409 Conflict Another transaction by user is already in progress for app:

Tags: java, google-app-engine

409 Conflict Another transaction by user XXX is already in progress for app: s~YYYY version: ZZ. That user can undo the transaction with "appcfg rollback".

Uploading a new version of the app on sep 23 2013 I got a 500 error. Since then I haven't been able to create new versions, I have followed the instructions by running:

```
C:\tools\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.4\bin>**appcfg.cmd rollback** c:\Users\workspace-jee\WWW\war
```

I get:

```
Sep 25, 2013 8:19:28 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed c:/Users/workspace-jee/WWW/war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Sep 25, 2013 8:19:28 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed c:/Users/workspace-jee/WWW/war\WEB-INF/web.xml
Sep 25, 2013 8:19:28 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed c:/Users/workspace-jee/WWW/war\WEB-INF/cron.xml
Sep 25, 2013 8:19:28 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed c:/Users/workspace-jee/WWW/war\WEB-INF/queue.xml
Sep 25, 2013 8:19:28 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.IndexesXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed c:/Users/workspace-jee/WWW/war\WEB-INF/datastore-indexes.xml
Sep 25, 2013 8:19:28 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed c:/Users/workspace-jee/WWW/war\WEB-INF/backends.xml


Beginning interaction for module default...
0% Rolling back the update.
**Success**.
Cleaning up temporary files for module default...
```

However the error persists. Any ideas?

Comment: This might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215140/google-app-engine-appcfg-py-rollback/5580673#5580673

Comment: Hello Drejc, as per my post, I tried exactly that and I get a success message. However that doesn't fix the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"If you have any settings related to modules (< instance-class >, < automatic-scaling > etc.), please remove them, rollback the previous transaction and try deploying again."

Helps for me. Just removed "< automatic-scaling >" block and then "appcfg rollback".

Comment: This works as a temporary solution, we are still waiting for google to fix this: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10021

Answer (score 1):

Same here. Please star this issue, since it seems to be a production problem given many of us are experiencing it:
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10021

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution provided by Cowen ATM

Google are aware of this issue and after following their advice, deployment was successful. their advice is copied below:

"We are aware of this issue where incorrect error message is displayed during deployment. If you have any settings related to modules (,  etc.), please remove them, rollback the previous transaction and try deploying again."

Note: even if you have performed the rollback many times, you will need to perform it again AFTER removing the above mentioned settings from your appengine-web.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

http://appengine-application.blogspot.in/2014/09/appengine-unable-to-update.html

you need to run the **rollback "project_War_Address"** command  in the appengine's sdk bin folder using cmd<>

Answer (score 0):

If your app is built using Maven, the easier way to rollback is to point your terminal to the directory from where you run the appengine deployments, and type `$appengine:rollback`.