# issues while deploying app to google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am on 1.8.1 GAE for java using eclipse on a mac book pro mountain lion.

On trying to deploy I am getting error:
Unable to update:

```
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=sakshumweb-hrd&version=3&
409 Conflict
Another transaction by user vik.ceo is already in progress for app: s~sakshumweb-hrd, version: 3. That user can undo the transaction with "appcfg rollback".

        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send1(AbstractServerConnection.java:293)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send(AbstractServerConnection.java:253)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.post(AbstractServerConnection.java:232)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.send(AppVersionUpload.java:810)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.beginTransaction(AppVersionUpload.java:543)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.doUpload(AppVersionUpload.java:135)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:386)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:55)
<dx59b2s3gxmlhdp3940000gn/T/appengine-deploy2012670164492350692.log" 17L, 1449C
```

I have already executed the below command which succeeds but the deployment still fails with the same error. Please note that in past I have done it without any issues 100s of times.

```
/Users/vivekkumar/Downloads/Sakshum/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.1.1/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.1.1/bin/appcfg.sh rollback war
Reading application configuration data...
Oct 11, 2013 9:43:02 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Oct 11, 2013 9:43:02 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed war/WEB-INF/web.xml
Oct 11, 2013 9:43:02 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed war/WEB-INF/cron.xml
Oct 11, 2013 9:43:02 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.IndexesXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed war/WEB-INF/appengine-generated/datastore-indexes-auto.xml


Beginning interaction for server default...
0% Rolling back the update.
Success.
Cleaning up temporary files for server default...
```

Comment: Are you deploying a gwt app?

Comment: yes its a gwt + GAE app

Comment: Can you paste yourmodule.gwt.xml file?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.0.1//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.0.1/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to='adminmodule'>
 <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User" />
 <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard' />
 <inherits name='com.google.gwt.gen2.Gen2' /> 
 <source path="client" />
 <source path='shared' />
 <add-linker name="xsiframe" />
 <entry-point class="vik.sakshum.sakshumweb.client.AdminDashBoard" />
</module>

Comment: ANOTHER:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to='sakshumwebgae'>
 <add-linker name="xsiframe" />
 <entry-point
  class="vik.sakshum.sakshumweb.client.SubscribeModule">
 </entry-point>
 <source path='client' />
 <source path='shared' />
 <entry-point
class="vik.sakshum.sakshumweb.client.BloodDonorRegister">
 </entry-point>
<entry-point class="vik.sakshum.sakshumweb.client.LoginModule">
 </entry-point>
<entry-point class="vik.sakshum.sakshumweb.client.FindBloodDonor"></entry-point>
<entry-point
 class="vik.sakshum.sakshumweb.client.EyeDonorRegister">
 </entry-point>
</module>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was the same issue (without GWT) and i solved deploy 409 error thanks [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19018402/gae-appcfg-rollback-not-working-409-conflict-another-transaction-by-user-is-alr)
Try it please, remove instance-class and automatic-scaling elements from appengine-web.xml.

Comment: removing   <instance-class>F4_1G</instance-class> tag fixed for me this issue

Comment: Hi, I don't have isntance-class and auto-scaling elements in my appengine-web.xml . I already tried the appcfg thing mentioned in the link. Please help. PS - I'm trying to deploy the default sample GWT app from a Eclipse 4.3 on Windows 8. The following is my appengine-web.xml

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>chrome-encoder-815</application>
  <version>1</version>
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
  <static-files>
    <include path="**" />
    <include path="**.nocache.*" expiration="0s" />
    <include path="**.cache.*" expiration="365d" />
    <exclude path="**.gwt.rpc" />
  </static-files>
  <system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
  </system-properties>
</appengine-web-app>

Answer (score 0):

You may need to cut down the number of permutations for the GWT compiler otherwise you'll end up with permutation explosion (the compiler will generate tons of files for each user agent, locale, ...etc), causing a timeout for app engine while deploying your app.

Try : [Soft Permutations](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/SoftPermutations)
OR : [Controlling Permutation Explosion](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/ControllingPermutationExplosion)