# How to rollback in App-engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I was deploying my app then suddenly my internet went down and the update was interrupted.

How do I rollback the update?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google App Engine: appcfg.py rollback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215140/google-app-engine-appcfg-py-rollback)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To roll back the update use the appcfg rollback command which is documented for Java apps [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp#Command_Line_Arguments) and for Python [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Python_Command-line_arguments).

If you are using Python on Windows then you would use:

`appcfg.py rollback C:\myappdirectory`

Just substitute `C:\myappdirectory` for the directory of your application. If you are using Java then you should substitute `appcfg.py` for `directory-to-java-sdk\appcfg.cmd` on Windows and `directory-to-java-sdk\appcfg.sh`on linux and mac.

Answer (score 1):

Rollback in App Engine

1. Place your project app.yaml in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine`
2. Open cmd and change the directory to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine` using `cd` command
3. Run the command 
   `python appcfg.py rollback app.yaml`